# TCL array index - what is the spec

Tags: tcl

I happen to run into this:

```
set a(()) 100
```

It is taken by TCL interpreter and added to array `a` an element whose index is () and value is 100.

I am perplexed. The [official TCL spec](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) does not say much about array index, it can take any character. That is fine. The problem is, how to retrieve it?

`puts $a(())` does not work:

```
can't read "a(()": no such element in array
```

The workaround are:

```
set i ()
puts $a($i)
```

or

```
puts [set a(())]
```

I am beating myself to make sense out of why `$a(())` does not work when "`a(())`" is happily taken, but cannot find any.

Can you help out? Or is this something we just recognize and live with it?

Comment: Why would you even do that? How is this even a question?

Comment: @MoDJ: nothing wrong with trying to figure out how a language works.

Comment: To my shame, I by mistake approved an edit to add the [array] tag to the question (I thought I was approving the deletion of the tag). Tcl arrays aren't in the same category as the kind of arrays the tag refers to. Please undo my mistake by rejecting the edit.

Answer (score 5):

`a(())` is a valid name for an array member, and as you say we can assign to it and retrieve its value using `set`:

```
set a(()) 100
set a(())
```

When invoking the `set` command, just like with all commands, the interpreter first splits the command line into words, performing substitutions as required, and then passes those words as arguments to the command. The first argument to `set` is the variable name: the `set` command uses the variable associated with the name or creates a new variable when assigning, alternatively raises an error if it can't find any such variable while retrieving.

`$` syntax is mostly syntactic sugar for the single-argument `set`, but does not necessarily use exactly one command line word for variable name. When the interpreter finds an unescaped `$` it attempts to find a sequence of characters that make up a variable name, and then substitutes the variable's value for the `$` and the name. The word can contain more text after this, and the word does not have to start with a `$`.

The interpreter is careful not to overmatch, so only a limited set of characters are allowed, and as soon as it finds an illegal character it stops and attempts the substitution using what it has found. If an opening parenthesis is found, the matching is relaxed somewhat (because it can expect to find an ending marker in the form of a closing parenthesis), so that different kinds of substitution can be performed within the index (which is why `set i () ; puts $a($i)` works).

In this case the matching stops if the word ends (i.e. whitespace is found; the substitution will fail because of the malformed variable name) or a closing parenthesis is found. This is why `$a(())` fails: the interpreter tries to use `a(()` as a variable name, followed by a `)` as the next character in the word. `$a((\))` *does* work, since escaping the first right parenthesis negates its syntactic meaning.

If the first character after the `$` is an opening brace, all characters up to the matching closing brace are used as a variable name, meaning that there can be no matching close brace within the parenthesis, but otherwise almost anything goes. This means that `${a(())}` works too.

Documentation: [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: It's also possible to use `upvar 0` to make an alias (with a simple name) to the array element.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, how to retrieve it?

The issue is exactly that the `$` syntax is restrictive. There are legal values for element names that you cannot write using the `$` form (for example, `()}{()` will *hugely* confuse the parser!) and in those cases, you need to use one of the alternate techniques you list. It's not usually a problem precisely because the places where these awkward cases come up are when you've not got elements under the control of the script — since why would you deliberately choose to make things awkward for yourself? — and then you're doing stuff like iterating over the set of names you've looked with `array names`, in which case you've already got the value in a variable and won't have the problem.

There are several ways to retrieve the value. Here are the ones I recommend (in no particular order):

1. `set theValueIs [set a(())]`
2. `set theElementIs (); set theValueIs $a($theElementIs)`
3. `upvar 0 a(()) alias; set theValueIs $alias`

There's also this, which works but isn't much to my taste:

4. `set theValueIs ${a(())}`